# Union MySQL - Procedimiento Multitabla

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Enunciado del problema:

2. Realizar un procedimiento con las dos funcionalidades siguientes:

• Listado ordenado alfabéticamente de los camareros indicando su
nombre, apellido, dni y el encargado que tiene.

• Listado ordenado alfabéticamente de los cocineros participantes
indicando su nombre,apellido, DNI y la especialidad que tienen.

Tengo el procedimiento bien, sin fallos. El caso es que al hacer la union para mostrar todos los resultados, el valor cocineros.especialidad se muestra en encargado como podréis ver en la imagen. ¿Hay alguna forma de mostrar otra columna para cocineros.especialidad? Espero que me hayáis entendido, adjunto foto de lo que quiero hacer y el script.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    drop procedure if exists proc2;

DELIMITER //

create procedure proc2()

begin

select empleados.nombre, empleados.apellido, empleados.dni, camareros.encargado from empleados, camareros
where empleados.codemple=camareros.codemple group by empleados.nombre
union
select empleados.nombre, empleados.apellido, empleados.dni, cocineros.especialidad from empleados, cocineros
where empleados.codemple=cocineros.codemple group by empleados.nombre;

end //

DELIMITER ;

call proc2();
```

Comment: Las especialidad es una tabla aparte o hace parte de la misma tabla de cocineros?

Comment: De la misma tabla de cocineros @AlejoFlorez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes añadir una columna vacia en cada una de las dos select que haces. Como union detecta que tienes el mismo numero de columnas, y del mismo tipo, te deja hacerlo sin problemas.

Así consigues tener una columna por cada tipo de dato de salida que necesites.

**Ejemplo:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc2;


DELIMITER //


CREATE PROCEDURE proc2()


BEGIN


SELECT empleados.nombre, empleados.apellido, empleados.dni, 
    camareros.encargado as Encargado, '' 
FROM empleados, camareros
WHERE empleados.codemple=camareros.codemple 
GROUP BY empleados.nombre
UNION
SELECT empleados.nombre, empleados.apellido, empleados.dni, '',
    cocineros.especialidad as Especialidad 
FROM empleados, cocineros
WHERE empleados.codemple=cocineros.codemple 
GROUP BY empleados.nombre;


END //


DELIMITER ;


call proc2();
```